# javascript fires if both div have one same class

Tags: javascript, css, class

Suppose, i have 2 div **'menu' & 'pipe'**. when i click menu pipe's width will be 100% but here i have 6 pair same like this so affecting one will affect all. "main code is given bellow."
now here i want js like this,

addclass '**addwidth**' in pipe div but that **pipe div** have one same class form the object(here, **menu div**) form which the click event is happen,

eg. ***menu one div*** is clicked so only ***pipe one div*** have to be affected.

.hasClass can help in some way but i dont know how.

help me for it's js,thanks in advance.

```css
.leftbox{
 width:100px;
 height:400px;
 background-color:lightgreen;
 display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.uprow{
 width:100px;
 height:100%;
 background-color:pink;
 display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.menu{
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 background-color:yellow;
}

.selected{
 background-color:green;
 border:2px solid blue;
}

.downrow{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:gray;
 display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
 
}

.pipe{
 width:10%;
 height:5px;
 background-color:aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftbox">
    <div class="uprow">
     <div class="menu one"></div>
     <div class="menu two"></div>
     <div class="menu three"></div>
     <div class="menu four"></div>
     <div class="menu five"></div>
     <div class="menu six"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="downrow">
     <div class="pipe one"></div>
     <div class="pipe two"></div>
     <div class="pipe three"></div>
     <div class="pipe four"></div>
     <div class="pipe five"></div>
     <div class="pipe six"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Where is the jquery part you tried? post it also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use [**`.eq()`**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) with [**`.index()`**](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

```js
$('.uprow .menu').on('click', function() {
  $('.downrow .pipe').eq($(this).index()).css('width', '100%')
})
```

```css
.leftbox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.uprow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.menu {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.selected {
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.downrow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.pipe {
  width: 10%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="leftbox">
  <div class="uprow">
    <div class="menu one"></div>
    <div class="menu two"></div>
    <div class="menu three"></div>
    <div class="menu four"></div>
    <div class="menu five"></div>
    <div class="menu six"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="downrow">
    <div class="pipe one"></div>
    <div class="pipe two"></div>
    <div class="pipe three"></div>
    <div class="pipe four"></div>
    <div class="pipe five"></div>
    <div class="pipe six"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to ask that is there any function which will check that menu (div) and pipe (div) both have one same element ,only that pipe can affect or else all other pipe will be (width=0),and can we add or remove class instead of changing css

Comment: @harshchelani I have provided a approach to compare.. And you can apply class instead of css..

Comment: thanks. prob. solved code is running. now i just need your help in one another matter,i want to add class on click and remove the same from others. like when i click it on main(0) then the class will add into pipe(0) and remove from other pipe(div).

Comment: can we add this css with media query?like after 500px page width the height have to be 100% not width?

Comment: @harshchelani, Have you tried doing it.. I do not see it _not working!_

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `click` event of the selected element like below.

In below example, clicking any element will change the width to 100% for that element only.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.pipe').click(function() {
    /* $(this) is the clicked/selected object. */
    /* Do your required action using $(this). Below is an example */
    $(this).css('width', '100%');
  });
});
```

```css
.leftbox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.uprow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.menu {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.selected {
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.downrow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.pipe {
  width: 10%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="leftbox">
  <div class="uprow">
    <div class="menu one"></div>
    <div class="menu two"></div>
    <div class="menu three"></div>
    <div class="menu four"></div>
    <div class="menu five"></div>
    <div class="menu six"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="downrow">
    <div class="pipe one"></div>
    <div class="pipe two"></div>
    <div class="pipe three"></div>
    <div class="pipe four"></div>
    <div class="pipe five"></div>
    <div class="pipe six"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yah but i want the action on one pipe at a time and in your js i want to click on menu (div) not pipe.

Comment: I want to ask that is there any function which will check that menu (div) and pipe (div) both have one same element ,only that pipe can affect or else all other pipe will be (width=0),and can we add or remove class instead of changing css